# $\frac{m(m+k+1)^n+k}{m+k}$ as closed form for subsequence of the partial sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences, closed-form-expressions

Let $a(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$a(n,m,k)=\frac{m(m+k+1)^n+k}{m+k}$$
There are many sequences in the OEIS that are special cases of a given sequence family:

- $a(n,1,1)$ - [A007051](https://oeis.org/A007051)
- $a(n,1,2)$ - [A047849](https://oeis.org/A047849)
- $a(n,1,3)$ - [A047850](https://oeis.org/A047850)
- $a(n,1,4)$ - [A047851](https://oeis.org/A047851)
- $a(n,2,1)$ - [A007583](https://oeis.org/A007583)
- $a(n,2,2)$ - [A034478](https://oeis.org/A034478)
- $a(n,2,3)$ - [A152596](https://oeis.org/A152596)
- $a(n,3,1)$ - [A083065](https://oeis.org/A083065)
- $a(n,3,2)$ - [A261399](https://oeis.org/A261399)
- $a(n,3,3)$ - [A034494](https://oeis.org/A034494)
- $a(n,4,1)$ - [A083066](https://oeis.org/A083066)
- $a(n,4,2)$ - [A083076](https://oeis.org/A083076)
- $a(n,4,3)$ - [A046636](https://oeis.org/A046636)
- $a(n,4,4)$ - [A083884](https://oeis.org/A083884)
- $a(n,5,1)$ - [A083067](https://oeis.org/A083067)
- $a(n,5,4)$ - [A093142](https://oeis.org/A093142)
- $a(n,5,5)$ - [A034659](https://oeis.org/A034659)

Let
$$\ell(n)=\left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor$$
$$f(n)=n-2^{\ell(n)}$$
$$\operatorname{tr}(2n+1)=0, \operatorname{tr}(2n)=\operatorname{tr}(n)+1$$
Here $f(n)$ is the same as $n$ without the most significant bit and $\operatorname{tr}(n)$ is the number of trailing zeros in the binary representation of $n$.

Let $b(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$b(n,m,k)=mb(f(n),m,k)+k\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\operatorname{tr}(n)-1} b(f(n)+2^j,m,k)$$

Let $s(n,m,k)$ be an integer sequence such that
$$s(n,m,k)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2^n-1}b(j,m,k)$$
I conjecture that
$$s(n,m,k)=a(n,m,k)$$

Is there a way to prove it?